# is possible to use binded param tags in different usl jstl tags?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a 2 different `<c:url>` tags in my jsp code. I need to use same `<c:param>` list to all of them.
It is possible?

eg:

```
<c:param var="userid" value="2"/>
<c:param var="username" value="xyx/>
```

I want to use above 2 param's in below two different urls.

```
<c:url var="getDetail" value="detail"/>
<c:url var="getProfile" value="profile/>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your url something like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

<c:url var="getDetail" value="www.google.com/userId=${userid}&userName=${username}"/>